# Formating help with dual boot

Tags: grub2, partitioning, mbr

first i will try to explain what i did and whats the problem.

So after almost 2 years i decide to format my notebook, i had one partition for Ubuntu and another one for Windows 8.1.

i havent been using Ubuntu in a long time so i decide to format the partition(this is where i start to do alot of mistakes).

From Windows using the program that let you expand/delete/format partitions i format the Ubuntu one and the swap one.
then i put my Windows cd, start the reinstall process, but when the pc restar it didnt boot it give me an error saying

"minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. for the first time........."

grub>

from what i understand i just erased Ubuntu and grub doenst know to do(if i didnt erase grub to)

when try starting from the cd/DVD but it gave me the same error, when i boot from the hdd(while smashig f12) it let me choose (Ubuntu manager, Windows boot manager) when i choose Windows the "new" instalation complete and let me go to Windows desktop, but actually it didnt erase anything

So, what can i do to erase everything and resintall Windows?.
(i cant boot from cd/DVD i try to boot from a Ubuntu 10.04 DVD that i have but it gave me the error)

Thanks for the help

Comment: i did not. installing ubuntu? windows?

Comment: Installing windows.

Comment: i will try to do it

Comment: I think I edited my comment - did I say re-install windows? If you did that and worked you can accept my post below as answer to close the thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my suggestion was to re install windows. Glad it worked out.